# C# - Excel Application is only working on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, excel

On my APP, when I press one button, my APP generate one excel file by:

```
Excel.Application xl = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(...);
Excel.Worksheet sheet = wb.ActiveSheet;
```

This code works when I compile it on Visual Studio. The problem is that, when I publish my code and I paste it on inetpub folder of my server, it doesn't work. When I press the button, the webpage doesn't do anthing (it doesn't show any error). But I know the code is failing on the first line I put above because I was studying it debugging.

I also tested it on my PC (installing IIS, etc) but it doesn't work neither...

Any idea? Thank you.

EDIT:

I saw the following error: Access denied:

The COM class generator for the component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} could not be retrieved due to the following error: 80070005 Access denied. (Exception of HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

Comment: you need to add the error details as well in your question

Comment: Never use Excel automation on a server, it is not meant to be used like that, let alone the licensing nightmare you're going to have.

Comment: Like I said, it doesn't show any error.

Comment: I just edit it with a error I saw on console.

Comment: Like I said, do not do this! You need to give your app too many permissions.

Comment: Is it possible to change your method of generating documents? if so I'll post some code that may help and save you from configuring permissions and office configuration on the server.

Comment: What do you mean with method? We need to generate excel with information about my app

Comment: You might need to give permission to the application. Give RW permissions to IUSRS

Comment: You are using a COM library to generate your excel files, try another API to facilitate the task without having to configure or install office on your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocumentFormat.OpenXml provides more elegant API than Office excel COM library which requires configuring permissions and installing office on the server.

Add a reference to DocumentFormat.OpenXml Nuget package then add the bellow function in your project, pass your excel file path into it.

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

public static void CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook(string filepath)
    {
        // Create a spreadsheet document by supplying the filepath.
        // By default, AutoSave = true, Editable = true, and Type = xlsx.
        SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

        // Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
        WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
        workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

        // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

        // Add Sheets to the Workbook.
        Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.
            AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

        // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
        Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.
            GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "mySheet" };
        sheets.Append(sheet);

        workbookpart.Workbook.Save();

        // Close the document.
        spreadsheetDocument.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm trying to test it but I'm getting an error only on the first line, on "SpreadsheetDocument.Create". "Type 'Package' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced."

Comment: Did you installed DocumentFormat.OpenXml Nuget package?

Comment: Yes, I did. And I added using DocumentFormat.OpenXml lines too.

Comment: Add the following using statements     using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
    using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
    using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the needed using statements

Comment: I solved it. I had to add WindowsBase reference to the project. Testing right now...I'll let you know if works

Comment: Works!!! Than you very much!! Sorry for not voting you positive, I can't :(. I still don't have the necessary reputation

Answer (score -2):

you need to install excel application in your server.

Comment: It's far more complicated than just this.

Comment: I have installed excel

Comment: This is not what the poster was asking for.